# Factor into primes in Dedekind domains that are not UFD's?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Does it make sense to factor numbers into prime numbers in Dedekind domains that are not unique factorization domains? I can't really see how it would make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dedekind domains, you have a factorisation of non-zero ideals as a product of prime ideals, and the decomposition is unique, up to the order of factors.

It is even for the case of non-UFD rings of integers in number fields that the notion of an ideal was introduced, in order to replace the factorisation of numbers as a product of  prime numbers.